# Protractor suites are not properly getting executed

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, protractor, suite

I have multiple specs so i created a suite for different specs.
Let's take the below scenario.

this is my suite structure in the conf file.

```
 suites:{
    forms:['specs/requestE.js'],
    search:['specs/findaSpec.js'],
    offers:['specs/offersPrograms.js','specs/destinationsSpec.js'],
    headerfooterlinks:['specs/footerlinksSpec.js','specs/headerMenuSpec.js']

},
```

When I run each spec individually it works correctly and generates the test results, but when I run the whole suite only the first one is working, others are not getting executed. As a result it gives timeout error.

Comment: Please show the `specs` in your protractor conf.js if you config it and the    cmd you used to execute running.

Comment: protractor protractor_conf.js --suite offers 

[this is just a collection of suite] @yong

Comment: did you config `specs` in your protractor_conf.js?  Try `protractor protractor_conf.js --suite=offers`

Comment: yes, I did, but it didn't work

Comment: @yong i don't why it's behaving like this, I also tried quitting the driver instance inside the afterAll function, but didn't work out.

Comment: Pleas show the `specs/offersPrograms.js` and `specs/destinationsSpec.js`, If you put `specs/destinationsSpec.js` before  `specs/offersPrograms.js` in suite: `offers`, I guess only ``specs/destinationsSpec.js` will be executed, please try and tell me the result.

Comment: Please show the timeout error message and you can see it can match one situation list in http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any test cases in first spec with fit('', function(){}) instead of it('', function(){}) ?

if thats the case, it'll just execute one spec while ignoring the rest

Comment: fit('') executes only that block of it. I use it to debug the tests/run a single test in the spec. what ive noticed is, if i run the entire suite, it'll just run that one particular spec and skips the others